# 'user.present' is not available

Tags: salt-stack

I installed [salt master and minion](http://saltstack.com/), and it look like right. It successfully run:

```
salt '*' file.rmdir dir_path=/root/abc user=root group=root mode=700
```

It's great. But I got a error when follow command run:

```
sudo salt '*' user.present name=salt
```

The error message:

```
'user.present' is not available.
```

I Google'd and haven't any result. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

When you are on the command line you are executing Salt "execution modules", which are imperative commands.

`user.present` is a Salt "state", which is a declarative, idempotent statement that you generally put inside a "state file" (a yaml file with an .sls extension)

To add a user from the command line you will need to use the user execution module. http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.useradd.html#salt.modules.useradd.add

It would look something like this:
`salt "minion id" user.add sarah`